# The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing while starting Apache server

Tags: apache, dll, xampp

I am not able to start my apache server.
I have tried this solution many times but still it's  showing the same error.

Solution I tried:

1. Install Windows Updates:
   Go to Start - Control Panel - Windows Update
   Check for updates
   Install all available updates.
   After the updates are installed, restart your computer.
   After the restart repeat the steps above again until no more updates are available.
2. Download the Visual C++ Redistributable:

For Windows 64-bit
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (64-bit)
For Windows 32-bit
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (32-bit)

3. Run the vc_redist.x64.exe (64-bit) or vc_redist.x86.exe (32-bit) and select Uninstall
4. Run the .exe again and select Install

I have tried all these steps but it's showing the same problem that api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll file is missing.
Please give me some solution.

Comment: It sounds like you might actually need to update the Universal C Runtime library https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226

Comment: Do I have to update my windows?

Comment: I have downloaded the package for windows 7 from this link: support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226 , but its searching for updates from yesterday.  Please give me some solution

Comment: What do you mean, _searching for updates from yesterday_ What is searching? If you mean standard windows updates, then yes, its always best to do all the standard windows updates

Answer (score 0):

Install Old version of xampp like 5.6.12 instead of using latest version. i getting the same problem when i trying the latest version of xampp 7.0.9 MySQL is running normally but Apache not started and after trying all solution like reinstalling xampp many times and setting up UAC and replacing port number 80 with 81 etc but nothing is working for me and finally after installing xampp version of 5.6.12 its started working easily and normaly so try these one